# Why do I keep getting 'Error: media_id field must be provided.' when using Twit NPM?

Tags: javascript

I have a function called postGirl that posts an image of an anime girl onto my twitter account. The images all download fine, so I have a folder that generates 400 images named girl1.jpg - girl400.jpg, so that doesn't seem to be the issue.

```
let postGirl = (girl, girlNum) => {
let numOfGirl = girlNum + 1;
let girlImage = './img/girl' + numOfGirl + '.jpg';
var girlImageFinal = girl[3];
console.log(girlImage);
let author = girl[0];
let tags = girl[1];
let hashtags = girl[2];
console.log('posting?');
var b64content = fs.readFileSync(girlImage, { encoding: 'base64' })

OtakuBot.post('media/upload', { media_data: b64content }, function (err, data, response) {
    var mediaIdStr = data.media_id_string
    var altText = 'Cute Girl'
    var meta_params = { media_id: mediaIdStr, alt_text: { text: altText } }
    console.log('inside media/upload');
    OtakuBot.post('media/metadata/create', meta_params, function (err, data, response) {
        if (!err) {
            let postMessage = '';
            console.log(tags[0]);
            postMessage = 'Cute picture with ' + tags[0] + ' and ' + tags[1] + ' by ' + author + ' #animegirls #' + author + ' #' + hashtags[0] + ' #' + hashtags[1] + ' #' + hashtags[2];
            var params = { status: postMessage, media_ids: [mediaIdStr] }

            OtakuBot.post('statuses/update', params, function (err, data, response) {
                console.log(data)
            })
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
})
```

}

I keep getting this error:

```
Error: media_id field must be provided.
at Object.exports.makeTwitError (C:\Users\Atlow\Documents\otakubot\node_modules\twit\lib\helpers.js:74:13)
at onRequestComplete (C:\Users\Atlow\Documents\otakubot\node_modules\twit\lib\twitter.js:344:25)
at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Atlow\Documents\otakubot\node_modules\twit\lib\twitter.js:364:7)
at Request.emit (events.js:327:22)
at Gunzip.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Atlow\Documents\otakubot\node_modules\request\request.js:1076:12)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
at Gunzip.emit (events.js:315:20)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1327:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {


code: null,
  allErrors: [
    {
      request: '/1.1/media/metadata/create.json',
      error: 'media_id field must be provided.'
    }
  ],
  twitterReply: {
    request: '/1.1/media/metadata/create.json',
    error: 'media_id field must be provided.'
  },
  statusCode: 400
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you checked out the `data.media_id_string` is not `undefined` in callback function?

Comment: Interesting. I checked that and sometimes it's undefined (then it throws the error) and other times it's not undefined and does not throw the error. This doesn't solve the issue, but it brings me a heck of a lot closer! Thank you for the tip.

Comment: @AndreThompson I couldn't give you detailed help because didn't know the exact internal logic of `OtakuBot`, but I'm glad it helped. :)